# How do I build a bridge when SimCity says "The slope is too steep"?

Tags: simcity-2013

Every time I try to create a bridge in my city over a lake it says "The slope is too steep".

I have tried to Google it but to no success.

Comment: I posted an answer.  If that doesn't help, consider posting a screenshot so that we can see the elevations on either side of the lake.  As is, we can only guess at your situation and give general advice about what the error means.

Answer (score 1):

When I Googled "The slope is too steep", it linked me to a [Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/CitiesSkylines/comments/2zzn0c/getting_slope_too_sleep_when_placing_premade/) which linked to [imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x05Im.jpg).

This suggests that you should make your bridge longer.  The error can indicate that the slope between the bridge surface and the interchange with the road at the end is too great.  If you move the connection further away from the main bridge, it should have more ability to make a gentle slope to the connection.

Comment: You propably knew this and are right regardless, but just so you know, your examples are from a different game.